# EPPlus при попытке доступка к DataValidators бросает ArgumentException

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Есть экселевский(xlsx) файл, чужой, созданный не мной. Открываю его через `EPPlus`

```
ExcelPackage ep = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(xlsxFileName))
```

и при попытке его сохранить(даже без изменений)

```
ep.Save()
```

получаю `ArgumentException` с сообщением `"Invalid schemaname: none"`.

Стек показывает, что происходит такое при попытке получить DataValidator, в котором проверяется тип валидатора.

```
   at OfficeOpenXml.DataValidation.ExcelDataValidationType.GetBySchemaName(String schemaName)
   at OfficeOpenXml.DataValidation.ExcelDataValidationCollection..ctor(ExcelWorksheet worksheet)
   at OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet.get_DataValidations()
   at RecalcAsync(String xlsxFileName) in Recalculator.cs:line 63
```

В исходниках видно, что проверяется тип валидатора, и если тип None, то получаем эксепшен. И сделать ничего не могу, так как попытка доступиться до коллекции валидаторов, выдаёт тот же эксепшен. Все такие коллекции валидаторов находятся в скрытых листах. Но даже удаление их ничего не меняет.

Может кто сталкивался с таким? Библиотека версии 4+, последняя бесплатная версия.

Comment: Экселем файл открывается? Если открыть экселем и пересохранить, проблема остается?

Comment: Да, проблема остаётся.